# Python parsing html mismatched tag error

Tags: python, html, parsing

```
30   <li class="start_1">
31               <input type="checkbox" name="word_ids[]" value="34" class="list_check">
32          </li>
```

This is a part of html file that I want to parse. But when I applied

```
uh = open('1.htm','r')
data = uh.read()
print data  
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
```

It showed

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 32, column 18

I don't know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse HTML with an *XML parser*; the latter doesn't have a concept of `<input>` not having a closing tag.

Use an actual HTML parser; if you want to access the result with an ElementTree-compatible API, use the `lxml` project, which [includes an HTML parser](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html). Otherwise, use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/) (which can use `lxml` under the hood as the parsing engine).

Answer (score 1):

To parse HTML in Python i use lxml:

```
import lxml.html
// html string
dom = '<li class="start_1">...</li>'
// get the root node
root_node = lxml.html.fromstring(dom)
```

after that you can play with it, for example using xpath:

```
nodes = root_node.xpath("//*")
```